# Python CSV: Isolate the index number of the row in a file (2d array structure) and put it into a variable

Tags: python, csv, variables

**Problem:** In the following repl.it https://repl.it/@oiuwdeoiuas/FINAL-PROGRAM-DATING-SYSTEM-2 [dating program], the code in the profile, searches for a username and then is able to change the 'wave count' of that user but it only works for user in row 0 of the text file. I want any given user who is logged in to be able to be identified and have their 'wave count' updated.

Currently the code only looks up a specific row (in this case row 0). I want to search for a field (username) and then identify which row the username is on, and then isoalte/read the row number into a **variable: username_index**

Below, I am using csv reader to search each row and each field for the username of the "logged in" user.

```
if field==username:
```

**The file contents are below, where the last field is the "wave count" (how many times a user has waved at another):**

```
JoeBbird,open123,Joe,Bloggs,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,patience,3
FishSmith,open123,Joe,Bloggs,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,laidback,0
KaraGray,open123,Joe,Bloggs,F,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,leadership,0
JMartin,open123,Jonathan,Martin,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,patience,0
```

If the field==username (e.g. if the logged in username is equal to any field), then I want to isolate the INDEX NUMBER of that field.

I then want to be able to use the username_index variable instead of 0 in this line of code to isolate the right user (not always the user in row 0)

```
 wavedcount=int(temporarylist[0][9])
```

**The relevant code is here:**

```
def profile(username):
  print("------Welcome to your profile---------")
  with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
    reader=list(csv.reader(f))
    temporarylist=reader
    for row in reader:
      for field in row:
        if field==username:
          username_index = field.index
        wavedcount=int(temporarylist[0][9])
  print("Waved at:",wavedcount)
```

I also tried this:

```
for row in reader:
      for field in row:
        if field==username:
           return rerader.line_num
           username_index = reader.linenum
           print("Welcome,",field)
           wavedcount=int(temporarylist[0][9])
```

which didn't work.

For an answer could you:

1. Suggest a solution using my existing code (and how to retrieve the index of any given username and put it into a variable so that I could use that variable in the array look ups)
2. Suggest a more suitable solution or alternative if there is one, if this (above) is inefficient.

UPDATE

Based on an answer below, I have tried:

```
def profile(username):
  print("------Welcome to your profile---------")
  with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
    reader=list(csv.reader(f))
    temporarylist=reader
    for idx, row in reader:
      for field in row:
        if field==username:
           username_index = idx
           print(username_index)
           print("Welcome,",field)
           wavedcount=int(temporarylist[0][9])
```

**but I get this error:**

```
 File "main.py", line 82, in profile
    for idx, row in reader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I changed it also to

temporarylist=**enumerate**(reader)

and got this error:

```
TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about your two questions. I think you need to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to create the for loop over the file. Using this you will have a list of tuples with the line index, along with the line content, and you would be able to recover the line index once you found the username:

1:

```
def profile(username):
    print("------Welcome to your profile---------")
    wavedcount = None
    with open("/tmp/dating.txt",newline="") as f:
        reader = list(csv.reader(f))
        temporarylist = enumerate(reader)
        for idx, row in temporarylist:
            for field in row:
                if field == username:
                    username_index = idx
                    wavedcount = int(reader[username_index][9])
                    break
    print("Waved at:", wavedcount)
```

2:

```
def profile_2(username):
    print("------Welcome to your profile---------")
    wavedcount = None
    with open("/tmp/dating.txt",newline="") as f:
        reader = list(csv.reader(f))
        temporarylist = enumerate(reader)

        filtered = [(idx, user[9]) for idx, user in temporarylist if username in user]

        if filtered:
            wavedcount = filtered[0][1]

    print("Waved at:", wavedcount)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tiago Gomes - will try in a minute. However, in the first instance, I just want the answer/solution using my existing code. I just want to isolate the ROW number into a variable that I can use. (which you haven't addressed)

Comment: just updated question - trying your suggestion but still doesn't work

Comment: I note you also added enumerate to the temporary list. Could you explain this (for beginners') in your answer. Even with that, I get this error:  TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Compoot the variable `username_index = idx` will store the **ROW number**. In your code, you are just creating a for loop over a list of lists, so, the object row didn't have any reference with the original list size. If you want to know where your current loop is inside the full object, you **have to use enumerate**

Comment: I think it works, could you explain what enumerate is in the answer (for a complete beginner) - "current loop inside the full object doesn't compoot....!